# This function should return the value of the second await. Currently it returns the value of the first await

Tags: react-native, async-await

I created a function called getAllCams in my ApiServices.js page.

```
async getAllCams() {
    try {
            const getAlarmListRes = await 
                fetch(`someurl`,
                {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: new Headers({
                        Authorization: `Basic ${base64.encode('user-id:1234')}`,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    })
            });
            if (getAlarmListRes.status === 200) {
                const newData = await getAlarmListRes.json();
                if (newData !== '') {
                    loggingService.debug('here is your array', newData.alarms);
                    return newData;
                }
                return ApiService.FAILURE;
            }
            loggingService.debug('Was not able to get alarm list for you', getAlarmListRes);
            return ApiService.FAILURE;
        } catch (e) {
            loggingService.debug('could not get alarm list', e);
        }
    }
```

when I call this function on CameraNotification.js page

```
componentWillMount() {
    loggingService.debug('component did mount');
    const listOfCams = apiService.getAllCams();
    loggingService.debug('here is your promise object', listOfCams);
}
```

I keep getting the result of the first await, which is simple a promise object that I convert to a JSON object in the second await.  From my understanding of await, listOfCams should return an array, not the promise object.  What is causing this to happen?  I've tried writing the code with .then() and the same thing happens.

Comment: `apiService.getAllCams()` is an async function, when you are calling this function you will receive `Promise` object only. Use `.then` to get the result. like `apiService.getAllCams().then(res => ...)`

Comment: Thank you for responding.  Two questions. 1. according to this https://www.dalejefferson.com/es7-async-await-with-react-native/ it's possible to have two awaits within the same function.  2.  const listOfCams = apiService.getAlarmList().then((res) => { res.json(); }); returns "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):" res.json is not a function

Comment: first of all, You can have multiple `awaits`, secondly don't convert `res` to JSON its the response from your `getAllCams` function which is plain data, not JSON.

Comment: I can read the array that I want when I type apiService.getAlarmList().then((res) => { console.log('here is something', res); });  How can I set res to a variable or create a variable that contains the array that I see in the console log?

Comment: store the returned value into `state` and read it in `render` or in other function.